# Fullcalendar apply border to highlight event

Tags: css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to add a border to the highlighted event (when a user clicks in a cell) like such:

```
.fc-highlight
{
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  border-color: #000 !important;
}
```

But as you can see in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9jc15r4/)**, it only applies the border to some edges. How do I apply a border to the whole cell?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's due to border collapsing. Use outline instead:

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid'],
  defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
  allDaySlot: false,
  timeFormat: 'H:mm',
  disableResizing: true,
  displayEventTime: false,
  displayEventEnd: false,
  slotDuration: '01:00',
  minTime: '00:00',
  maxTime: '23:00',
  selectable: true,
  firstDay: 1,
});

calendar.render();
```

```css
.fc-highlight {
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  outline:1px solid #000;
  outline-offset:-1px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/interaction/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.css">

<div id="calendar">

</div>
```

Or box-shadow:

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid'],
  defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
  allDaySlot: false,
  timeFormat: 'H:mm',
  disableResizing: true,
  displayEventTime: false,
  displayEventEnd: false,
  slotDuration: '01:00',
  minTime: '00:00',
  maxTime: '23:00',
  selectable: true,
  firstDay: 1,
});

calendar.render();
```

```css
.fc-highlight {
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #000 inset;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/interaction/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.css">

<div id="calendar">

</div>
```

Comment: Although it works (and I'm gonna accept your answer) the color of the outline is not entirely black..seems like it has some opacity because we're using outline instead of border.

Comment: @Linesofcode fullcalendar apply an opacity to `.fc-highlight` you can add `opacity:1!important` and it will be full black